# Comparison of dates to today and other dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel file that contains dates and want to write a formula so that the dates that are passed are in red, the dates that are between today and four weeks from today are in yellow, and the dates in a month or more are in green.

Can you help me?

Comment: It's called "Conditional Formatting" and are a somewhat easy thing to configure in your stylesheets. If you need more help, please provide more info. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+conditional+formatting

Comment: If you do need to ask a question, [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) might be a better place to ask. I would recommend you read the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) re: conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks @SimonJensen ; Zack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select whole sheet content and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(A1>TODAY()+27,A1<>"",CELL("format",A1)="D1")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of Green formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then repeat with:

```
=AND(A1<TODAY()+28,A1<>"",CELL("format",A1)="D1")
```

for Yellow and for Red:

```
=AND(A1<TODAY(),A1<>"",CELL("format",A1)="D1")
```

You might need to adjust the cutoffs (`27` and `28`) to suit your purposes.

The formulae are as long as they are to format dates wherever found in the spreadsheet (since, until OP offered their own A, there was no sign where the dates were to be found) without formatting blank cells or those not formatted as Date.

Comment: You can actually just use `greater than` or `less than` instead of formulas: `Format only cells that contain` > `Cell value`, `greater than`/`less than`, cell with `=today()`. In the manager select the cells/columns/rows that the rule applies to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @pnuts

***SOLUTION***

I have solved the problem using conditional format

These are the rules I used:

= B12

= UND (B12 <= HEUTE () + 28; B12> = HEUTE ()) and then set the yellow color

= B12> HEUTE () + 28 and then set the green color

**The formals are in german ( HEUTE=TODAY and UND=AND )**